# Pass debug_backtrace() in Wordpress filter

Tags: filters, hooks, performance

As you know, [debug_backtrace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) function has a large output.
I need to pass it in my filter.

```php
$meta = apply_filters( 'filtername' , $meta , debug_backtrace() );
```

Does this have a big impact on site performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can limit calls and ignore args like this to reduce performance:

```
// Limit backtrace to last 3 calls as we don't use the rest
// Limit argument was introduced in PHP 5.4.0
$backtrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed!